# React design pattern question for data retrieval

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

i’m building a roombooking system in React. On many pages its a simple crud, like rooms, users, etc.

Whats a good pattern for getting lookup data?

How i now solved it. Is on startup I get lots of data in one request. Then on for example the page with the bookings, I present it with looping through the bookings. And then on the booking object there is for example a userid, so the I search for the email in the array with users. It works quite fast, but it seems a bit messy.

Here's some example code:

```
 <OverlayTrigger
          key={`tooltiptrigger-booking--${booking.id}`}
          placement='top'
          overlay={
            <Tooltip id={`tooltip-${booking.id}`}>
                {getFullname(booking.user_id)} <br/>
                from {toDateString(booking.startdate)} until {booking.enddate ? toDateString(booking.enddate) : 'indefinite'} <br/>
                status : {bookingtypes?.find(b => b.id === booking.bookingtype_id)?.name} <br/>
            </Tooltip>
          }>
            <div className={`booked ${getWidthClass()} ${getOffsetClass()} ${getBorderLeft(booking)} ${getBorderRight(booking)} ${getAddedClass()}`}
              ref={fieldRef}
              onClick={() => setShow(true)}
              style={{backgroundColor: bookingtypes?.find(b => b.id === booking.bookingtype_id)?.bg_color,
                        color: bookingtypes?.find(b => b.id === booking.bookingtype_id)?.color}}
              key={`maindiv-${booking.id}`}>
            {getFullname(booking.user_id)}
            </div>
        </OverlayTrigger>
```

Comment: Where are you making the API request? How are you presenting the data? Is in a table? If so could you be using pagination? Or did all data needed be loaded directly?

Comment: At the moment I do one big request in the context and retrieve parts through that
like 
const { bookings, rooms, roomtypes,  user} = React.useContext(RoomBookingContext) as IRoomBookingContext;

Comment: I the context I do:
 axios.get(apiUrl + '/api/all').then((response) => {
                setRooms(response.data.rooms);
                setAreas(response.data.areas);
                setUsers(response.data.users);
                setBookingtypes(response.data.bookingtypes);
                setRoomtypes(response.data.roomtypes);               
            }).then(() => setLoading(false));

Comment: Ok, should it be possible to fetch bookings in chunks? For example fetch only books for the current week? Then make another request for the the next week on demand?

Comment: no not really, there are not so many and it much faster like that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.